# How to make cumsum this matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, cumulative-sum

```
A= [ 1 2 4
     2 3 1
     3 1 2 ]
```

so that the answer from above matrix should be:

```
B = [ 1  3  7 
      9 12 13 
     16 17 19 ]
```

thanks

Comment: http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html

Comment: What, `B = cumsum(A)`? You just answered your own question...

Comment: no, i didnt answer my question. i have A as input. and i wanna have B as ouput. how can i do that?, can you help me??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiddling with `cumsum` and `reshape` can get you there:

```
B = reshape(cumsum(reshape(A', 1, [])), size(A))'
%# Equivalent to: B = A'; B = reshape(cumsum(B(:)), size(A))'
```

This yields:

```
B =

     1     3     7
     9    12    13
    16    17    19
```

Comment: Nice (+1). Instead of the inner `reshape` you could also use `subsref(A', struct('type','()','subs',{{':'}}))` which is basically a `A'(:)`. Don't know whether this is faster than `reshape`, though.